# Nodejs SOAP module - timout option

Tags: node.js, soap

How can I set the timeout for `soap.createClient` and/or `client.myFunction`? It is not mentioned in the documentation. If it not possible, is there a work around?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After an hour of trying, i found it, basically it uses request, and wsdl_options will override [request](https://github.com/request/request) option. You can follow below example. :))

```
soap.createClient(url, {wsdl_options: {timeout: 5000}}, callback)
```

ref to: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#options

Comment: `{wsdl_options: {timeout: 5000}}` Didn't work for me. Adding `{ timeout: 5000 }` after `callback` arguement at `client.myFunction` option, could work though.

Answer (score 2):

This is what it is mentioned in node-soap documentation

```
client.MyService.MyPort.MyFunction({name: 'value'}, function(err, result) {
    // result is a javascript object
}, {timeout: 5000})
```

Options are set as 3rd parameter after callback function.

https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#options-optional

Basically it uses `request` module for http transport. So the options of request module are also valid for the soap module

Comment: Those options don't seem to be available for the interface i'm using: Client.method(args, callback).

Comment: this is worng, for the createClient method options object is the 2nd argument after url

https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soapcreateclienturl-options-callback---create-a-new-soap-client-from-a-wsdl-url-also-supports-a-local-filesystem-path